# Broadcom BCM4331 can not connect to WPA networks

Tags: 12.04, wireless, macbook, broadcom

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my early-2011 MacBook Pro. I installed the broadcom wireless driver and I cannot connect to WPA secured networks. How do I fix this?

Comment: Show output from **sudo lspci -v**, for 'Network controller'.  Should show details of Broadcom device.

Comment: Or, more simply (and 'Broadcom' specific): **lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4**

Answer (score 0):

Try the instructions at:

[WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

You need to confirm the exact version of Broadcom chip, and how to make this work on **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**